# my android app shows up as incompatible with all devices

Tags: android, google-play

I just published an android app today, and no matter what `uses-feature` I remove, what country I make the app available in, it shows up as not available in any device whatsoever.

Here's a link to the app [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rupyacard). The app is working on the devices that I have but shows up as incompatible on them as well! I have no clue why this would be the case given that I have already had over >8 apps published earlier.

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />
        <!--
             Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
             notification message. See README() for more.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.White"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.OtpActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_otp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.White"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AddAadhaarActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pan_and_aadhaar"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.White"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AddPanActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pan_and_aadhaar"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.White"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.White.Home"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.InvitationsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.White.Home"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.PayNowActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.White"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.PaymentSentActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.White"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.CameraActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.White"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.IntroductionActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.Gradient">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".services.MessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".services.InstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-fexceptions"
            }
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':zxing-wrapper')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a very high version in your graddle, about the version that can support each device.

It could also be no other country for lack of multilingual support.

[Here documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html?hl=en-419)

Comment: Added the AndroidManifest. and gradle.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured the problem! It turns out adding `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to my Manifest adds a feature `android.hardware.screen.portrait` which no device has! I removed this line, and used java to force portrait only mode. This has fixed the issue for me!